# Rails Custom Validation with RSpec undefined method error

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I received undefined method `beginning_of_year' for nil:NilClass when I run rspec for my custom validation.

```
mDate = order_date.beginning_of_year
```

It run fine when I tested it with browser but I kept getting error if I try to run RSpec.

Comment: looks like `order_date` is not getting set somehow. could you please add more details about the spec and method which you testing in spec?

Comment: I made mistake of not adding if so my custom validation will only be used if order_date is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure order_date is not null before calling beginning_of_year method